# Multiple calls to staticExpects on mocked objects

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I am tring to write test cases for my controller in cakephp, so far i have managed to mock the controller and include the auth component which is used in my controller function. the problem is it seems that i can call staticExpects only once, which means that i can define a return value for only one function call, i don't want that, i need to call staticExpects more than once within the same test case.

Here is a part of my code.

```
$this->TasksController = $this->generate('Tasks', array(
'components' => array('Session','Auth' => array('User'), ) ));

  $this->TasksController->Auth->staticExpects($this->any())
    ->method('User')
    ->with('userID')
    ->will($this->returnValue(224));
     $this->TasksController->Auth->staticExpects($this->any())
    ->method('User')
    ->with('accID')
    ->will($this->returnValue('some ID here'));
```

whenever i do this and run the test it gives me this error

Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked zero or more times
Parameter 0 for invocation AuthComponent::user('userID') does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify when the static methods are called using $this->at(index).

```
$this->TasksController->Auth->staticExpects($this->at(1))
    ->method('user')
    ->with('userID')
    ->will($this->returnValue(224));

$this->TasksController->Auth->staticExpects($this->at(2))
    ->method('user')
    ->with('accID')
    ->will($this->returnValue('some ID here'));
```

If you're not sure when they are called try each expectation one by one until the error messages will give you what is called

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'userID'
+'accID'
```

One last thing, the correct method name is "user" and not "User"